# How to crawl images inside links of a page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need the crawler to go to the links inside a website and scan images there. I've managed to get this far but I'm confused.

I'm trying to do something like this but I'm sure there's gonna be an easier way.

```
from bs4 import *
import requests as rq
import os
import sys
from urllib.parse import urlparse

page_url = sys.argv[1]
depth = int(sys.argv[2])
crawl = str(page_url)
r2 = rq.get('https://www.' + crawl + '' + '/')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "html.parser")
links = []
images = []

link_urls = soup2.select('a')


def url_validator(link):
    try:
        result = urlparse(link)
        return all([result.scheme, result.netloc])
    except:
        return False


def crawl_images(link):
    requested_link = rq.get(link)
    images = BeautifulSoup(requested_link.text, "html.parser")
    image = images.select('img')
    for img in image:
        print(img['src'])
        return img['src']


for link_url in link_urls[:depth]:
    links.append(link_url['href'])
    for link in links:

        # print(link)

        if url_validator(link):
            crawl_images(link)
```

I try `python3 new_crawler.py imdb.com 3` which should print sources of images crawled in 3 links inside imdb.com but it's not printing anything.

Comment: Put your code in a function. Then you can call it recursively for the links in the page.

Comment: Note that the URL in `href` may be a relative URL. You need to resolve it relative to the containing page's URL. Use `urllib.parse.urljoin()` for this.

Comment: can you provide a snippet please?

Comment: `rq.get(urllib.parse.join('https://www.' + crawl + '' + '/', link))`

Comment: The `for link in links:` loop should not be inside the `for link_url in link_urls[:depth]:` loop.

Comment: I'm not even sure why you have two loops. Can't you just do `link = link_url['href']` and then request that? Why do you need the `links` list.

Comment: Yes I can link = link_url['href']
and then request that by rq.get(link.text, "html.parser")?

Comment: @Barmar how should I use this part?
rq.get(urllib.parse.join('https://www.' + crawl + '' + '/', link))

Comment: That replaces `rq.get(link)`. That's the snippet you asked for, right?

Comment: oh I was asking about the first comment sir

Comment: That was assuming you also want to follow the links from the next set of pages, and keep crawling recursively. It's more complicated than I feel like writing for you.

Comment: you have to assign response to variable `response = rq.get(link)` and work with this response `BS(response.text)` instead of `BS(link.text)`

Comment: Yeah i fixed that yesterday. I'll update the question with the current code.

Comment: if you have new code then you should add it below old code - now comments and answers doesn't match to your code.

Comment: what wrong with this code? Do you get error message? Show it in question (not in comments). Do you get wrong results? Show url so we could test it - maybe page needs different code. Different pages may have different structure an they need different code.

Comment: if code is working but you need only to clean it then you should rather ask [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: BTW: maybe first clean code - remove imports which you don't use, put all functions directly after imports, use `f-string`, see more on [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: don't use `return` inside `for`-loop because you get only first result. inside for-loop you should append to list and after loop you should return this list.

Comment: if it doesn't print then maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. Maybe it can't find any links or images . And you could add URL for which you tested code - maybe it needs different code. OR maybe page uses JavaScript to add elements. May modern pags use JavaScript for `lazy loading` images - so page add `src` to `img` when user scroll page. But BS can't run JavaScript and it this may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: The code is supposed to work in a way that it should find images inside any url inputed.
I'll try to debug.

Comment: if page uses JavaScript then it may NOT find images. `requests` and `BS` can't run JavaScript.

Comment: now for some urls it returns the images and for others there's nothing. I think that may be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You want to crawl through the images, correct? Try this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as rq


URL = ""
source = rq.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")


image_links = soup.find_all("img")

for img in image_links:    
    print(img['src'])
```

Add the website's url to the constant `URL` that you are trying to scrap. The page's `img` tags should all be saved in the `image_links` variable.

Comment: They said they want to go to the links and crawl the images there.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but how can I crawl images inside the links of that website?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with. It's not working how it's supposed to but the time for the task is up and I decided to share anyway.

```
from bs4 import *
import requests as rq
import sys
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import json

page_url = sys.argv[1]
depth = int(sys.argv[2])
crawl = str(page_url)
r2 = rq.get('https://www.' + crawl + '' + '/')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "html.parser")
link_urls = soup2.select('a')
links = []
images_sources = []


def url_validator(link):
    try:
        result = urlparse(link)
        return all([result.scheme, result.netloc])
    except:
        return False


def crawl_images(link):
    requested_link = rq.get(link)
    images = BeautifulSoup(requested_link.text, "html.parser")
    image = images.select('img')
    for img in image:
        images_sources.append(img['src'])
        results = {
            "imageUrl": img['src'],
            "sourceUrl": link,
            "depth": depth
        }
        json_object = json.dumps(results)
        with open("results.json", "w") as f:
            f.write(json_object)
            f.close()
            return results


for link_url in link_urls[:depth]:
    links.append(link_url['href'])
    for link in links:
        if url_validator(link):
            crawl_images(link)
```